How to make test property source work when annotated at config class
I try to configure a class which will use test property when doing springboot test

application.properties

meta=value



application-test.properties

meta=value-test


@Configuration
@TestPropertySource("/application-test.properties")
public class AppConfig {
}


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {AppConfig.class, TestService.class})
//@TestPropertySource("/application-test.properties")
public class SpringTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestService testService;

    @Value("${meta}")
    private String value;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(value); // "value"
    }
}

When @TestPropertySource("/application-test.properties") annotated on SpringTest, "meta" value would read from application-test.properties as "value-test".
But when @TestPropertySource("/application-test.properties") annotated only on AppConfig.class, this would not work. "meta" value would read from application.properties as "value".
What I want to achieve is that each spring test which try to load AppConfig.class would use application-test.properties automatically.
How can I achieve this?

You are making things overly complex. DItch the @TestPropertySource and annotate your test class with @ActiveProfiles("test") so that Spring Boot will automatically load both application.properties and application-test.properties.
